# I need to search particular a record in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called "students" and a table called "stud_info" containing student information such as "indexno" "name" "studresults". I want to search the details of students by using their index number only. I tried to do this using an example I found on the internet but it searches from Keywords only.

Is there a way to search a database table using only by giving a particular number such as "indexno"?

```
+----+---------+--------+-------------+
| id | indexno | name   | studresults |
+----+---------+--------+-------------+
|  1 |  123456 | Andrew | Pass        |
|  2 |  125845 | John   | Pass        |
|  3 | 2258996 | Kevin  | Pass        |
|  4 | 1258896 | Emily  | Pass        |
+----+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Here is the code,

index.php file

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

search.php file

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db("students") or die(mysql_error());

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 


    $min_length = 3;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stud_info
            WHERE (`indexno` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){


                echo "<p>Index No:".$results['indexno']."<br />Name:".$results['name']."<br />Results:".$results['studresults']."</p>";

            }

        }
        else{ 
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `indexno` is an INT field, then need to use `IN()` operator instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: `like '%indexno%'` is for wildcard matches; you just need `indexno = $query`

Comment: Why are you using the `mysql` extension when it's long been deprecated? Use `mysqli` or PDO.

Comment: I'm new to PHP language and I found this example on the internet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `LIKE` but the comparator `=` (is exactly equal to).

So your `WHERE`-clause should look like this:

```
WHERE (`indexno` = '".$query."')
```

`LIKE` does provide a method for loose matching with wildcards (`%`). So if you write:

```
`indexno` LIKE '%96'
```

You get the records with the following `indexno` as a result:

> 22589**96**
>   12588**96**

Because both end with `96` and the wildcard before `96` tells the `LIKE` comparator that everything can be at the beginning of the compared values as long as they end with `96`.

In your case it's even more loose matching because you do have a wildcard at the beginning and the end of the string. So if you enter `2` your `LIKE` clause looks like that:

```
LIKE '%2%'
```

which will match each and every record of your sample data provided because there can be anything before and/or after the string `2`. This is true for every record because every record contains at least one `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :
In index.php file:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

In search.php file just change :

```
$query = $_POST['query'];
```

And let me know the result before and after these changes .

Answer (score 0):

replace your database name correctly
you have created database as students and you have inserted

```
mysql_select_db("stud_info") or die(mysql_error());
```

change it first as

```
mysql_select_db("students") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -3):

you are making a pattern search using "Like" syntax make use of "=" in your query

THIS IS WHAT MUST BE IN YOUR QUERY "SELECT * FROM results where indexno=".$query

Comment: `where indexno=$qurey` not `id`.

Comment: You don't need to yell